# How to show allow location popup in flutter webview

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I tried to load my custom webview link in flutter application, where it has the allow location access popup. I'm using webview_flutter plugin with setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted) but below popup is not displayed and weblink is not loaded properly in my application. Can anyone help me on this?

[image]

Comment: ask permission in your flutter apps.
if you guarantee location ppermisson for your flutter app, it will also guarantee permission location to your webveiw

Comment: actually not only location, it applies to all permission. 
for example, if you want to open camera from webview, you have to give permission to your app. for example here :https://medium.com/gitconnected/attach-files-images-and-videos-from-iframe-webview-in-flutter-app-effbe064e3e

Comment: i have enabled the location permission and location service, but still when i load the webview, it prompt for the allow location for that particular web url. There webview is not showing the above popup

Comment: actually, no need to any pop up anymore in your webview. since you already guarantee the permission from the app.

if your web need to get gps position, it should works